# How can I use a `where` clause in a linq query that is also doing a `group by`?

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq

I have the following Linq statement:

```
var packs = from r in new XPQuery<Roll>(session)
            join p in new XPQuery<Pack>(session) on r.Pack equals p
            group new { r, p } by new { r.Pack } into gb
            select new
            {
                Length = gb.Sum(x => x.r.Length),
                ALength = gb.Where(a => a.r.Grade == "A").Sum(x => x.r.Length),
            };

gcPack.DataSource = packs;
```

When it executes, I get a Runtime Error with the following:

> Additional information: Property path 'r' is incorrect for type 'DataRepository.Roll' because member 'DataRepository.Roll.r' does not exist.

I know `ALenght = gb.Where(a => a.r.Grade == "A").Sum(x => x.r.Lenght)` causes the runtime error because when I remove it code executes without any errors.

Is it possible to use a `where` in a `select` statement like this?

Comment: Causes problem? What problem exactly?

Comment: it doesn't work but when I omit the last part it would work.

Comment: We are not telepathic I'm afraid. You need to describe the problem in details. In what way does it not work? Does it give you an error? If so, what is the error? Please [edit] the question with more detail.

Comment: I got this error : Additional information: Property path 'r' is incorrect for type 'DataRepository.Roll' because member 'DataRepository.Roll.r' does not exist.

Comment: Is it posible to use where clause in select statement?

Comment: Did you read my comment? Please [edit] the question, don't post this details in the comments.

Comment: I've done this @DavidG

Comment: I noticed in your sum method, you spelt length wrong. Does fixing that solve the issue?

Comment: no the problem is something else @DylanCorriveau

Comment: Ah I see now. In your length statement, what is 'r' in this case? (x.r.Length)

Comment: I've reordered the question for clarity. Pulled the kernel of the question out of the middle and put it at the bottom so it's easy to find. I also connected the error message with the code that's generating the  error. If `Lenght` really is `Length` - I recommend fixing that to reduce the load on the reader of remembering that's an intentional spelling.