# how can I add a column to IQueryable object and modify its values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, grid, devexpress

```
        var packs = from r in new XPQuery<Roll>(session)
                    select new
                    {
                        Number = r.number
                        Selection = new bool()
                    };
        gcPack.DataSource = packs;
```

I want to add another column to my grid control with: Selection = new bool(). It will be added to the grid but I can't change its rows' values. How can I add to my grid a column  that I can change its values

Comment: Anonymous types are designed for the readonly case. If you need something editable simply define a proper class and use that instead of the anonymous one in your linq query.

Comment: can yo give me an example? @Ralf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example for using a non-anonymous class.

```
public class MyLovelyClass
{
    public Int32 Number { get; set; }
    public bool Selection { get; set; }
}

var packs = from r in new XPQuery<Roll>(session)
            select new MyLovelyClass()
            {
               Number = r.number                
            };
gcPack.DataSource = packs;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974930/how-can-i-use-where-clause-in-group-by-statement-in-linq can u help me @Ralf